# Tomcat installed on remote server. how to check on local browser

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, ubuntu

I have installed apache tomcat on remote ubuntu server.
I have installed and configured it properly(`ps -ef | grep tomcat` lists the tomcat process).
I have deployed a war file of my app in webapps directory.
I have public ip address of the server and also i know the listening port of tomcat.

When I enter the public_ip_address_of_server:tomcat_listening_port/my_application_name on the address bar of browser in my local windows machine, 
I get "could not connect to public_ip_address_of_server:tomcat_listening_port" error

What might be the cause? Your help will be highly appreciated.

NOTE: I have tested tomcat is running properly on server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check /etc/hosts file and make sure you have the public IP listed there

Comment: @Satya I already mentioned it as: public_ip<space>random_name in hosts file but problem persists

Comment: have you checked apache logs , they might give you a better idea

Comment: No clue there too. As I told the error message says "could not connect to public_ip_address_of_server:tomcat_listening_port" hence i think the server url itself is not accessible.

Comment: then check via iptables for tomcat port being forwarded to apache , if not recreate a rule and then restart iptables and hit the url

Comment: can you access the tomcat manager site from the outside http://<ip-address>:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help.
I was able to resolve the issue.
I know it is weird but it wasn't any firewall or server issue.
I just installed tomcat manager and uploaded my war file from there and just restarted my tomcat.
It helped my application running

Thank you all once again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a n/w issue to me or at-least a connectivity issue. Few things you can give a try..

1. Can you access the app from the same machine using
   public_ip_address_of_server:tomcat_listening_port/my_application_name
   (I have seen your NOTE. Don't try local host, use the ip directly.)
2. Can you try pinging this machine from other box.
3. Can you just hit public_ip_address_of_server:tomcat_listening_port
   and see if the tomcat default page is comming. If not then its not
   able to connect only and its a n/w issue.

Comment: Also can you try this on the ubuntu box... https://www.google.co.in/search?q=get+my+ip&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta and see it matches with your external ip what ever you have purchased? If you want to do using command prompt try this: lynx --dump http://whatismyip.org

Answer (score 0):

1) Ping to the ip_address where tomcat server is running; If ping fails then first fix network issue.

2) If ping succeed then see is there any firewall configured on the network; If configured then bring that down.

3) Try running this command on local machine to see you are able to connect to the port of the server machine

```
     nmap -p port ipaddress (for tcp)
     nmap -sU -p port ipaddress (for udp)
```

4) If fails, then run the above command in the server machine to see it works there. If works then you can definitely say there is some network or firewall issue.